# How to create directories using the name of source files with make

Tags: makefile

I am trying to write a Makefile which will take a directory that has some files in it.

`file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt other.conf`

I want to make folders `file1/ file2/ file3/` with the respective file and other.conf in there

I then want to zip that folder.

My problem with my current Makefile is I'm not sure how to create folders and targets based on the filename. I'm not even sure it's possible.

My current makefile

```
dir_guard=@mkdir -p $(@D)
CP=cp -r

file1/file1.txt: file1.txt
    $(dir_guard)
    cp file1.txt file1/file1.txt

file1/other.conf: other.conf
    $(dir_guard)
    cp other.conf file1/other.conf

file1.zip: file1/other.conf file1/file1.txt
    zip file1.zip $?

build: file1.zip

clean:
    -rm -r *.zip
```

Comment: If you have à variable $(filename)  that is by example file1/file1.txt you can obtain 'file1'  like this : $(basename $(notdir $(filename))). Now I am not sure how it can be in the target name and I cannot test it for the moment. If the variable is file1.txt you Will have the full path and name like this : $(basename $(filename))/$(filename)

Comment: Is the directory a significant artifact of your build process? Or you need just the zip file as an output?

Comment: @Leon The directory is not important. I just need the zip file at the end

Comment: I guess I could always make a target of the zip file and go straight without a folder. But, I'm still unsure how to make a generic target based on the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm still unsure how to make a generic target based on the filename.

Typically you use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html),
e.g.

**Makefile**

```
files := file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
zips := $(files:.txt=.zip)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(zips)

%.zip: %.txt other.conf
    zip $@ $^

clean:
    rm -fr *.zip
```

which will run like:

```
$ make
zip file1.zip file1.txt other.conf
  adding: file1.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: other.conf (stored 0%)
zip file2.zip file2.txt other.conf
  adding: file2.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: other.conf (stored 0%)
zip file3.zip file3.txt other.conf
  adding: file3.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: other.conf (stored 0%)
```

Other cribs:

- `(files:.txt=.zip)`

  - [6.3.1 Substitution References](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html)
- `zip $@ $^`

  - [10.5.3 Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)

Here's [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

**Later**

> Is there a way to make the list of files automatically all files with a .txt extension?

- `files := $(wildcard *.txt)`

  - [4.4 Using Wildcard Characters in File Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html#Wildcards)

Comment: Is there a way to make the list of files automatically all files with a .txt extension?

Answer (score 0):

If the directory is not a significant artifact of your build process, then you can create a simple shell script (say `create_zip`) and use it in your makefile as follows:

**makefile**

```
...
file1.zip: file1.txt other.conf
    create_zip $?
```

**create_zip**

```
#!/bin/bash

startdir=$(pwd)
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

trap "rm -rf $tmpdir" EXIT

cd $tmpdir

name=$(basename $1|sed -e 's/\.[^.]\+//')
mkdir $name
for file in $@;
do
    cp $startdir/$file $name
done

zip -r $startdir/$name.zip $name
```

Comment: This suffers from *All the world's a bash* syndrome, not enough double quoting and a useless semicolon.